# Logic issue, adding Buttons to UI based on database entries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fmdb

In my `SQLite` database (`FMDB`) i have some attributes as listed below;

> Module | Student1 | Student2 | Student3 | Student4 | Student5

One `Module` may have a minimum of 2 `students` and a maximum of 5 `students`. So based on the number of students i have to display Buttons.

If the number of student are 3, then i should display 3 buttons. For Ex : if the database entry is as

> Science | jack | Tom | - | Debra | -

note that the - sign is an empty record. So if we come across a entry with - sign we have to ignore it. So according to the above query we have 3 students and we should display 3 buttons. (If there were 4 students we should display 4 buttons and etc...)

How could i read the values from the database, and base on that answer add buttons to the UI ?

note: I don't have any proper code to demonstrate my working. I am lost in this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So first learn about interacting with with a SQLite FMDB [Here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/)

Then, create some kind of for loop combining the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616594/how-can-i-store-uibuttons-in-an-array) to create UIButtons and add them to an array, then displaying only the UIButtons in the array.

The positioning of the buttons onscreen is just a bit of simple math.

Comment: You have posted the same links. Could you repost the correct links

Comment: fixed the links. It was missing the one showing how to store it in an array.